# heightForHeaderInSection not getting called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to change the `tableHeader` height, font, etc...

I implemented `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource` and added `heightForHeaderInSection` and `viewForHeaderInSection`. But these two methods are not getting called. Other methods such as `numberOfRowsInSection` / `cellForRowAtIndexPath` are working fine. I can see the table but with no header :(

Any idea?

here is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.poHeader.itemList count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"*******height");
    return 44.0;
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"***in viewForHeader In section");

    UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 166, 300.0, 44.0)];
    UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    headerLabel.opaque = NO;
    headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    headerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(2, 166, 300.0, 44.0);

    headerLabel.text = @"Part No.   Description   Ext Cost"; // i.e. array element
    [customView addSubview:headerLabel];

    return customView;
}
```

Comment: Even if the delegate methods were called, the headerLabel would appear in the wrong place (too low).  Its origin should probably be 0,0 instead of 2,166 since it's a subview of customView.

Answer (score 20):

Almost a year later, but I guess you have only set the data source and not the delegate?

You'll have to have something like this in your controller:

```
myTableview.delegate = self;
myTableview.dataSource = self;
```

You mentioned that numberOfRowsInSection / cellForRowAtIndexPath are getting called. Both belong to `UITableViewDataSource` and not to `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: Almost 2 years later, this deserves to be checked as accepted, since is the right one.

Comment: I don't know why, but even though the table view was connected to the view controller as both delegate and datasource, somehow the delegate connection was broken. Couldn't trace it but this answer gave me a way to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

for swift in addition to setting delegate
declare UITableViewDelegate conformance for a class or extension in question